# Trying to return JSON object from Express and Node app. Getting a blank object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, express

Help me out please, I feel like its something with the res.json(). It works if I call it after the first request, but not the second. The actual application is pretty basic right now, it just scrapes some user data off of a social media like twitter or instagram, and then returns the json object. Thanks!

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  let twitterHandle = req.query.twitter;
  let instagramHandle = req.query.instagram;

  let twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/" + twitterHandle + "?lang=en";
  let instagramURL = "https://instagram.com/" + instagramHandle;

  var json = {};

  console.log(twitterHandle);
  console.log(instagramHandle);

  // The structure of our request call
  // The first parameter is our URL
  // The callback function takes 3 parameters, an error, response status code and the html
  if (twitterHandle != "") {
    request(twitterURL, function(error, response, html) {
      // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request
      if (!error) {
        // Next, we'll utilize the cheerio library on the returned html which will essentially give us jQuery functionality
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        // Finally, we'll define the variable we're going to capture
        // We'll be using Cheerio's function to single out the necessary information
        // using DOM selectors which are normally found in CSS.
        var twitterFollowers = $(
          "#page-container > div.ProfileCanopy.ProfileCanopy--withNav.ProfileCanopy--large.js-variableHeightTopBar > div > div.ProfileCanopy-navBar.u-boxShadow > div.AppContainer > div > div.Grid-cell.u-size2of3.u-lg-size3of4 > div > div > ul > li.ProfileNav-item.ProfileNav-item--followers > a"
        )
          .text()
          .replace(/\D/g, "");

        var twitterFollowing = $(
          "#page-container > div.ProfileCanopy.ProfileCanopy--withNav.ProfileCanopy--large.js-variableHeightTopBar > div > div.ProfileCanopy-navBar.u-boxShadow > div.AppContainer > div > div.Grid-cell.u-size2of3.u-lg-size3of4 > div > div > ul > li.ProfileNav-item.ProfileNav-item--following > a"
        )
          .text()
          .replace(/\D/g, "");

        // And now, the JSON format we are going to expose

        json[twitterFollowers] = twitterFollowers;
        json[twitterFollowing] = twitterFollowing;

        // Send the JSON as a response to the client
      }
    });
  }
  if (instagramHandle != "") {
    request(instagramURL, function(error, response, html) {
      // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request
      if (!error) {
        // Next, we'll utilize the cheerio library on the returned html which will essentially give us jQuery functionality
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        // Finally, we'll define the variable we're going to capture
        // We'll be using Cheerio's function to single out the necessary information
        // using DOM selectors which are normally found in CSS.
        var instagramFollowers = "chicken";

        var instagramFollowing = "chicken";

        // And now, the JSON format we are going to expose
        json.instagramFollowers = instagramFollowers;
        json.instagramFollowing = instagramFollowing;

        // Send the JSON as a response to the client
      }
    });
  }
  res.json(json);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: the calls to things like `request()` are asynchronous so you're returning `res.json(json)` before it has been populated.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'm playing around with the res.json() right now. Where do you think is the best place to put it? I thought putting it in the spot I had was the best, because I make the requests, store the data, and then return the object.

Comment: Put it in a function and call that function from inside the callback of the two `request()`s where it says "Send the JSON".

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous so you are sending the response before you get the callback with the result of the calls to `request()`. You need to send the request from within the callback, either via `res.json()` or a call to another function.

```
// get the request here
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  // do some stuff
  if (foo) {
    // make a request
    request(url1, function(err, res, html) {
      // get the callback with the result
      const json = { foo: 'bar' };

      // call the function to send the response inside the callback
      return res.json(json);
    });
  }
  // don't send response here since it will get called before the callback
  // even though it is further down in the code since it's asynchronous.
});
```